# How to write this python snippet in functional programming style?

Tags: python, functional-programming, toolz

How can I write the line below in functional python using e.g. [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)?

```py
dct1 = {1: 1, 2: 2}
dct2 = {2:2}
dct3 = {2:2, 3:3}

common_keys = set(dct1.keys()) & set(dct2.keys()) & set(dct3.keys())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try to write this in a *functional* style:

```
from functools import reduce

dct1 = {1: 1, 2: 2}
dct2 = {2: 2}
dct3 = {2: 2, 3: 3}

shared_keys = reduce(set.intersection, map(set, map(dict.keys, [dct1, dct2, dct3])))
```

First we create a list of the dictionaries.

Then we `map` the `dict.keys` function to each of them.

Then we map them to `set` giving us sets of keys for each dictionary.

Finally, we `reduce` those sets with the `set.intersection` function.

Comment: This answer highlights how the methods of python data types are implicitly functions to be called on their instances and that by calling `cls.method(instance)` we something close to a pure function.

Answer (score 2):

Actualy your question is very unclear. I will try to help you with:

First of all, you don't need to use `set` over `dict.keys()`:

```
dct1.keys() & dct2.keys() & dct3.keys()
# returns {2}
```

You can use `reduce` function for your puprose:

```
from functools import reduce    


def key_intersection(*dicts):
    if len(dicts) == 0:
        return set([])
    if len(dicts) == 1:
        return set(dicts[0])
    return reduce(lambda l, r: l & r.keys(), dicts[1:], set(dicts[0]))


key_intersection(dct1, dct2, dct3)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `set(dicts[0])` be `set(dicts[0].keys())` in two places in your code?

Comment: @Chris, it gives the same result because of default iterator through dict uses keys.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean way using `toolz`.  Using [`toolz.pipe`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.pipe) and [`toolz.curried`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/curry.html#the-curried-namespace) often makes things easier to compose and easier to read:

```py
import operator as op
from toolz import pipe
from toolz.curried import map, reduce

pipe(
    [dct1, dct2, dct3],
    map(op.methodcaller("keys")),
    reduce(op.and_)
)
```

I found your question clear, and I would say this is the best functional `toolz`-style way of doing this.  This pattern is powerful and can be extended to more complicated problems, so it is worth learning.